# R - finding ordered patterns in strings with grep

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to search particular patterns in a set of strings.

Given these two vector of strings:

```
actions <- c("taking","using")

nouns <- c("medication","prescription")
```

I want to find any combination of **action** + **noun**, in this particular order, not *noun + action*. For example, using the following text I want to detect the combination:

- *using medication*
- *taking medication*
- *using prescritpion*

Using the following text:

```
phrases <- c("he was using medication",
              "medication using it",
              "finding medication",
              "taking the left",
              "using prescription medication",
              "taking medication drug")
```

I have tried using `grep("\\b(taking|using+medication|prescriptio)\\b",phrases,value = FALSE)` but it's clearly wrong.

Comment: `+` is a quantifier meaning look for the previous token 1 or more times. You need to insert a wildcard token `.` in front of it so the space between the words can grow or shrink: `grep("taking|using.+medication|prescription", phrases)`

Comment: Try `grep(paste0("(",paste(actions, collapse="|"), ")\\s+(", paste(nouns,collapse="|"),")"), phrases, value=FALSE)`, see http://ideone.com/e7Ae5S

Comment: Not quite there yet, I do not want the fourth phrase to be a match becasue there is only the *action* but not the *noun*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build the alternation groups using your `actions` and `nouns` values and put them into a bigger regular expression:

```
actions <- c("taking","using")
nouns <- c("medication","prescription")
phrases <- c("he was using medication","medication using it","finding medication","taking the left","using prescription medication","taking medication drug")
grep(paste0("(",paste(actions, collapse="|"), ")\\s+(", paste(nouns,collapse="|"),")"), phrases, value=FALSE)
## => [1] 1 5 6
## and a visual check
grep(paste0("(",paste(actions, collapse="|"), ")\\s+(", paste(nouns,collapse="|"),")"), phrases, value=TRUE)
## => [1] "he was using medication" "using prescription medication" "taking medication drug"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/e7Ae5S)

The resulting regex will look like

```
(taking|using)\s+(medication|prescription)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8cBVh/1).

**Details**:

- `(taking|using)` - an alternation group matching either `taking` or (`|`) `using`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(medication|prescription)` - an alternation group matching either `medication` or `prescription`.

Note that `(...)` *capturing* groups may be replaced with `(?:...)` *non-capturing* ones in order to avoid keeping the submatches in memory.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll check the demo out!